# “Cohomological equation” in dynamical systems

Tags: reference-request, homological-algebra, ds.dynamical-systems, mp.mathematical-physics, cohomology

Let $$\dot{x}=Ax+v_r(x)+v_{r+1}(x)+ \dots$$ with $x \in \mathbb{C}^n$ and $v_r: \mathbb{C}^n \to \mathbb{C}^n$ a homogenous, polynomial function of order $r.$

Then, being able to find a suitable $h$ in order to eliminate the term $v_r$ of order $r$ with a change of variable $y=x+h(x)$ amounts to being able to solve the so-called *(co)homological equation* $$L_Ah(y)=-v_r(y)$$ which in turn is equivalent to not having resonances of order $r$ between the eigenvalues of $A.$

Here $L_A$ is an operator whose domain and codomain is the $\mathbb{C}$-vector space with basis given by $P_{i,j}=y^{j}e_i,$ where $e_i$ is the standard basis and $y^{j}=y_1^{j_1}\cdots y_n^{j_n}$ with $\sum j_i=r.$ A simple calculation gives $L_Ah(y)=Dh(y)Ay-Ah(y).$

**Q.**

> I would like to understand how does this relate to (co)homology and
> where does this terminology come from. I appreciate references where
> this kind of point of view is addressed too.

Note that this was also posted in [math.stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2048269/the-origin-of-the-name-homological-equation) by someone else  but despite being upvoted it did not receive any answer in 5 and a half years, hence the crosspost.

Comment: If you'd like to know why people use cohomological language, you'll find helpful the following entry on Tao's blog https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2008/12/21/cohomology-for-dynamical-systems/

Comment: that is certainly interesting but it seems to be about cohomology for dynamical systems in general and doesn’t seem to address the “cohomological equation” in normalisations that I ask about. Or does it?

Comment: ah sorry I misread your comment you were not claiming that it answers my question.

Comment: I assume that your $x$ is a vector? In that case it seems that your $L_A$ acts on vectors of homogeneous polynomials, and not on homogeneous polynomials as you claim?

Comment: @VladimirDotsenko I edited to make more clear what I meant.